# Magento product tree customization

Tags: magento, tree, customization, product, cart

I require Magento product customization before adding to cart. I know Magento can do this, however I require the customization to be done in a tree fashion. Let me explain.

I have a product, with several group of options separated by type.
After choosing an option, additional configuration options should be displayed. This means that I have the following config tree:

- Group 1

  - Custom property 1

    - Option 1

      - If option 1 is selected, show Custom property A with it's own options
      - If option 1 is selected, show Custom property B with it's own options
    - Option 2
    - Option 3

      - If option 3 is selected, show Custom property C with it's own options
      - If option 3 is selected, show Custom property D with it's own options
  - Custom property  2
- Group 2

  - Custom property  3
  - Custom property  4
  - Custom property  5

Everything has to be configurable, and selectable BEFORE adding to cart. The product value will change while changing these options.

Here is an example of what I want: http://www.1001opticiens.fr/lunettes-de-vue/48-ralph-lauren-rl6017-en-plastique-noir-rose.html
Just hit "Choisir ce modele" and the list of configurations will open. Sorry, the site is in French, but you should get the general idea.

Does something like this exist? Or should I start from scratch?
I found something like this done in Prestashop. Would it be possible to "import" such an extension? (I doubt it really)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible to do but it requires extending the core classes and quite a bit of frontend JS and phtml work. There is an extension that does this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-options.html